# Ссылка на класс Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо создать список, содержащий в себе ссылки на классы, чтобы в дальнейшем выбирать из них случайный и создавать его экземпляр. Во время создания такого списка вылетает исключение.

> error CS0119: 'A' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

на строке с кодом

```
List<parent> list_classes = new List<parent>() {A, B, C};
```

---

Вот версия этого кода на языке Python:

```py
import random

class parent:
    def printt(self):
        print(self.value)

class A(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'A'

class B(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'B'

class C(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'C'

list_classes = [A, B, C]

random_class = random.choice(list_classes)

random_class().printt()
```

Вот версия того же кода на языке c#:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class parent {
    public char value = 'P';
    public void printt() { Debug.Log(this.value); }
}

public class A : parent {
    public char value = 'A';
}

public class B : parent {
    public char value = 'B';
}

public class C : parent {
    public char value = 'C';
}



public class test: MonoBehaviour
{   
    void Start()
    {
        List<parent> list_classes = new List<parent>() {A, B, C}; // error CS0119: 'A' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

        parent random_class = list_classes[Random.Range(0, list_classes.Count)];

        new random_class().printt();
        
    }
}
```

Прошу помочь решить данную проблему.

Comment: В листе нужно хранить типы, их можно получить с помощью typeof(ClassName). Все остальное есть в интернете. А еще посмотрите про оформление кода C#)

Comment: `List<Type> list_classes = new List<Type>() { typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C) };`
`parent random_class = (parent)Activator.CreateInstance(list_classes[Random.Range(0, list_classes.Count)]);`

Comment: @aepot он, вроде бы, хочет создавать экземпляры классов из списка. Хотя, может он неправильно выразился и вы правы

Comment: @KuzCode Вы правы, мне нужно каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр. Воспользовался Вашим способом, вылетает следующее: `error CS0118: 'random_class' is a variable but is used like a type`

Comment: `Parent` наследует `MonoBehavior` или нет? Если да, то `new` использовать нельзя как и `Activator`, можно только `GetComponent`.

Comment: @aepot Если переводить его код с питона на шарп, то вы правы, но если как он говорит "выбирать из них [списка типов] случайный и создавать его экземпляр", то без рефлексии не получится

Comment: @pashkin5000 ошибка CS0118 воникает изза того, что вы пишете `new` в строке `new random_class().printt();`

Comment: @KuzCode на самом деле можно не через активатор сделать, а через откомпилированное [выражение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162809/12888024). Если производительность важна, то надо забыть про активатор. Хотя может что-то с тех древних времено поменялось.

Comment: @aepot ну его по скорости вроде бы бустили, а там не знаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного не так наследование делается, и в списке наверное нужны типы.

```cs
public class Parent {
    protected char value = 'P';
    public void Print() {
        Debug.Log(value);
    }
}

public class A : Parent {
    public A() {
        value = 'A';
    }
}

public class B : Parent {
    public B() {
        value = 'B';
    }
}

public class C : Parent {
    public C() {
        value = 'C';
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{   
    void Start()
    {
        List<Type> list = new List<Type>() { typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C) };
        Type randomType = list[Random.Range(0, list.Count)];
        Parent randomItem = (Parent)Activator.CreateInstance(randomType);
        randomItem.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вероятно Вы меня не поняли, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы список содержал именно ссылки на классы, а не их экземпляры. Обратитесь к моему примеру на питоне.

Comment: @pashkin5000 окей, исправил ответ.

Comment: Всё работает, благодарю